# Print formatted line BASH

Tags: bash, format, line

this is the problem:

I have an input file, like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZseL.png)

and i have to obtain this result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I13fv.png)

now, how can i succeed in having the tabulation on the right?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Don't post screenshots, post your actual code (and it's faster too).

Comment: I suggest to take a look at awk‘s or bash‘s printf command.

Comment: I can't use Awk :(

Comment: All images are perfect for see how it must work, i haven't code because i have to write it!

Answer (score 0):

something like this should probably work:

```
cut -d' ' -f1,3,4,9,10 /tmp/mbox_stats.txt | column -t
```

however, this looks like a school assignment where the assignment specifically has to do with right-aligning columns. you can do that with some `printf`. here's a little hint about that.

code:

```
echo -e "a abc abcdefg\nbasdrafewf x z" | xargs printf "%s %s %s\n"
```

output:

```
a abc abcdefg
basdrafewf x z
```

code:

```
echo -e "a abc abcdefg\nbasdrafewf x z" | xargs printf "%10s %10s %10s\n"
                                                         ^^   ^^   ^^
```

output:

```
         a        abc    abcdefg
basdrafewf          x          z
```

code:

```
cut -d' ' -f1,3,4,9,10 /tmp/mbox_stats.txt | xargs printf ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this command align the text on the left, and i must have the text aligned on the right.
This is my problem :/